# How to sum properties of the objects within an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, sum, inject

I understand that in order to sum array elements in Ruby one can use the inject method, i.e.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5];
puts array.inject(0, &:+)
```

But how do I sum the properties of objects within an object array e.g.?

There's an array of objects and each object has a property "cash" for example. So I want to sum their cash balances into one total. Something like...

```
array.cash.inject(0, &:+) # (but this doesn't work)
```

I realise I could probably make a new array composed only of the property cash and sum this, but I'm looking for a cleaner method if possible!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
array.map(&:cash).inject(0, &:+)
```

or

```
array.inject(0){|sum,e| sum + e.cash }
```

Comment: This goes over `array` twice though, which might not be advisable if there are lots of elements. Why not just use a proper block for `inject`? Also `reduce/inject` directly takes a symbol argument, no need for `Symbol#to_proc` :-)

Comment: note that you don't need to send a block, `inject` knows what to do with a symbol: `inject(0, :+)`

Comment: Yuri, I +1'd your answer, but the second snippet doesn't look good, better a functional: `array.inject(0) { |sum, e| sum + e.cash }`

Comment: i thought it might be a hash my fault)

Answer (score 63):

In Ruby On Rails you might also try:

`array.sum(&:cash)`

Its a shortcut for the inject business and seems more readable to me.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html

Comment: If you're using Rails, this is the way to go.

Comment: Note that if your array is the result of some kind of filtering on an ActiveRecord object, e.g. `@orders = Order.all; @orders.select { |o| o.status == 'paid' }.sum(&:cost)`, then you can also get the same result with a query: `@orders.where(status: :paid).sum(:cost)`.

Comment: If the records are not stored in the DB, the sum will be 0, where inject would work.

Comment: More on @Dennis comment: if you are using Rails 4.1+, you **can't** `array.sum(&:cash)` on an activerecord relation, because it want's to make an [ActiveRecord sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) like so: `array.sum(:cash)` which is massively different (SQL vs. Ruby). You'll have to convert it into an array to make it work again: `array.to_a.sum(&:cash)`. Quite nasty!

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger if possible, it is preferred to do sql sum vs ruby sum, no?

Comment: It depends on the use case: Say you need to load the array of objects on the page, doing Ruby calculation will avoid querying `select sum(field) from table` but if you only need the sum value, for sure `select sum(field) from table` is faster than `select * from table` parsed in objects and then summed in Ruby.

Answer (score 11):

`#reduce` takes a block (the `&:+` is a shortcut to create a proc/block that does `+`). This is one way of doing what you want:

```
array.reduce(0) { |sum, obj| sum + obj.cash }
```

Comment: `#reduce` is an alias for `#inject` in 1.9+, btw.

Comment: +1 for not iterating over `array` twice. The alias is also there in 1.8.7 btw.

Comment: as Michael says that's more space-efficient that map+reduce, but at the cost of modularity (small in this case, no need to say). In Ruby 2.0 we can have both thanks to laziness: `array.lazy.map(&:cash).reduce(0, :+)`.

Comment: I wonder why there is such an alias. They have got the same length.

Comment: @Nerian: In Smalltalk this was called `inject:into:` whereas several other languages call folds `reduce` (e.g. Clojure, Common Lisp, Perl, Python). The aliases are there to accomodate people with different backgrounds. Same for `map`/`collect`.

Answer (score 5):

Most concise way:

```
array.map(&:cash).sum
```

If the resulting array from the map has nil items:

```
array.map(&:cash).compact.sum
```

Answer (score 3):

If start value for the summation is 0, then sum alone is identical to inject:

```
array.map(&:cash).sum
```

And I would prefer the block version:

```
array.sum { |a| a.cash }
```

Because the Proc from symbol is often too limited (no parameters, etc.).

(Needs Active_Support)

Answer (score 2):

Here some interesting benchmarks

```
array = Array.new(1000) { OpenStruct.new(property: rand(1000)) }

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('map.sum') { array.map(&:property).sum }
  x.report('inject(0)') { array.inject(0) { |sum, x| sum + x.property } }
  x.compare!
end
```

And results

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
             map.sum   249.000  i/100ms
           inject(0)   268.000  i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
             map.sum      2.947k (± 5.1%) i/s -     14.691k
           inject(0)      3.089k (± 5.4%) i/s -     15.544k

Comparison:
           inject(0):     3088.9 i/s
             map.sum:     2947.5 i/s - 1.05x slower
```

As you can see inject a little bit faster

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use initial in inject and plus operation can be shorter

```
array.map(&:cash).inject(:+)
```

Comment: You are right about the symbol argument, but if `array` can be empty, you want the argument: `[].inject(:+) #=> nil`, `[].inject(0, :+) #=> 0` unless you want to deal with the `nil` separately.